# css z-index on elements with "position" property

Tags: html, css, reactjs, z-index

In my react app I have one component which has position:fixed, bottom: 0 properties.
When I scroll down and receive footer I need that component hide behind footer by adding z-index: 0 to fixed component and z-index 9999 to footer but it doesn't work. After giving negative values to fixed component it starts work wrong with other components on the same page.

Comment: Did you set the position property for all needed elements? z-index only works when element is out of the normal flow

Comment: Could you phrase your question better and use some markup?

Comment: Is the footer positioned as well? It would need to be for z-index to work. Positioned elements will display on top of unpositioned elements.

Comment: `Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).` - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: If you post your css for the elements involved maybe you will get better help. My obvious things is to have the footer in a heigher z-index from the begining, and don't forget to set `position: relative;` on it incase it does not have it. Also, it is totally unnecessary to use such high z-index numbers, depending on how have it structured but you could use like a `z-index: 10;` on the one element and `z-index: 11;` on the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to footer:

```
posistion: relative; 
z-index: 99;
```